# Upload image by Froala to server with custom response format

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, froala

I am using Froala editor.
I would like to upload images to own server, as described in [documentation](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/concepts/image-upload) response format should be `{ link: 'path/to/image.jpg' }`, but my server returns response with another format.

Is it possible to use custom response format with Froala, probably by handle some event?

Comment: Also looking for this.

Comment: I didn't find solution. So at this moment I just send additional parameter "format" to server and form response according to it. Just few lines of code, but in any case would be nice to use custom format on client.

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing to do with the server response model via the front. its model is designed at backend and if you need to change it you maye parse the Json you get and change the model as you wish. to get the model exactly as you mentioned above you should talk to your backend team.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using cloudinary.com for uploading and serving images and I also have no control on the response. My temporary solution was to monkey patch the JSON.parse method like this (coffeescript) :

`var _parseJSON = JSON.parse;
JSON.parse = function(j) {
  var response = _parseJSON(j);
  response.link = response.secure_url;
  return response;
};`

I really hope to find a more elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

Froala seems to not have a mechanism to modify the response from the server when it manages uploads. There is a suitable froala event for this `froalaEditor.file.uploaded`, but it only can abort the upload process. May be in the future it will be updated to suit such cases

However what you want is absolutely doable. First you'll need to add a query param to `imageUploadURL` prop in your froala config, e.g. `const froalaConfig = {imageUploadURL: '/yourUploadsEndpoint?fromFroala'}`. This param is needed to distinguish requests that were actually made by froala from others.

Then we will do a little monkey patch to `XMLHttpRequestObject`, which is internally used by froala to make http requests:

```
const accessor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'responseText')

Object.defineProperty(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'responseText', {
  get() {
    const responseText = accessor.get.call(this)
    // here we can check if response url includes our previously set query param
    if (this.responseURL.includes('?fromFroala')) {
    // r is our response object
      const r = JSON.parse(responseText)

      return JSON.stringify({ link: <path to your uploaded image url here> })
    }

    return responseText
  },
  configurable: true,
})
```

This should do the trick until froala switches to another data fetching API.

Answer (score 0):

The [image.uploaded](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/events?&_ga=2.74444370.1168793263.1528827948-605900671.1521894515#image.uploaded) event is being triggered as soon as there is a response from the server. You could use the response parameter of this event together with the [image.insert method](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/methods?_ga=2.4669939.1168793263.1528827948-605900671.1521894515#image.insert) to add the image in the editor.

Also, it is important to return false at the end of the callback to prevent the default editor upload chain.

Below is a code snippet for that:

```
$('.selector')
  .froalaEditor()
  .on('froalaEditor.image.uploaded', function (e, editor, response) {
    // Parse response to get image url.
    var img_url = ... ;

    // Insert image.
    editor.image.insert(img_url, false, null, editor.image.get(), response);

    return false;
  });
```